# Background image not shown in android phonegap jquerymobile app

Tags: css, html, jquery-mobile, cordova, background-image

I'm trying to show a background image on an Android phonegap app based on jQuerymobile.
This is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquerymobile.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" />

    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquerymobile.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="Main" class="main-page">
      <ul data-role="listview" data-filter-reveal="true" data-filter="true"
                data-filter-placeholder="Insert the city here..." data-inset="true">
        <li><a href="#LimonePiemonte">Limone Piemonte</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Artesina">Artesina</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Tonale">Tonale</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /page -->
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the CSS (index.css)

```
.main-page {
    background:  transparent url(img/alpettalownologo.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

But I see no image in background. What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm guessing your `url(img/alpettalownologo.jpg)` is not correct as this would mean it's in a sub directory of your CSS files.

The location of the background image needs to be in relation to that particular CSS file, so maybe `url(../img/alpettalownologo.jpg)` as a guess would work, depending on your file structure.